# How to make a Ruby view load the Bootstrap css library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a ruby on rails application, and I am trying to have buttons inherit some of the styles from the bootstrap css library.

I already have the import of the css library defined elsewhere in the app, and it works.

Now I am using HAML and trying to render a link as a button like this:

```
      =link_to((t "some_path"), some_url(disclosure), :class => "btn" )
```

but the btn isn't getting recognized.  What do I need to do to reference the bootstrap.css 
correctly?

In the other namespace where the twitter bootstrap css is being recognized, I have a manifes file which looks like this:

```
/*
 * THIS IS THE MANIFEST FILE FOR THE LAYOUT
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-responsive
 *= require bootstrap_overrides
*/
```

but i am not sure if I need it for the other code I am working on. And if I do, how do I configure it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the bootstrap-sass gem

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Then import bootstrap in `application.css.scss`

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Not part of your question, but I also include some JS elements from bootstrap into `application.js`

```
//= require bootstrap
```